# @FormParameter in spring -mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

In spring-mvc, in controller code i have seen the form parameters explicitly passed . Why is this done?

```
public ModelAndView methodXX(
        @FormParam("arg1") String arg1,
        @FormParam("arg2") String arg2,
        @FormParam("arg3") String arg3,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

If the call were as follows:

```
public ModelAndView methodXX(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
```

The arg1,arg2,arg3 could still be obtained by using

request.getParameter("arg1") and so on for the others.
What is the benefit of using FormParam?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `@FormParam` annotation in Spring MVC, at least not in any version I am aware of. Spring MVC has [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

The main benefit is to reduce the code repetition in calling

```
request.getParameter("arg1");
```

However, `@RequestParam` also has other parameters, namely `required` and `defaultValue`. With `required` set to `true`, Spring will throw exceptions if `getParameter` returns `null`. With `required` set to `false`, Spring will call `getParameter` and pass whatever it finds, whether it's `null` or an actual value.

With `defaultValue`, you can set a default value if `getParameter` returns `null`.

So instead of doing

```
String arg1 = request.getParameter("arg1");
if (arg1 == null) {
    arg1 = "default value";
}
```

you simply add the following as a method parameter

```
..., @RequestParam(value = "arg1", defaultValue = "default value") String arg1, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type in your request,
you can send data in the POST body.

method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

In this case, the data in POST request body has to be of the format
arg1=1&arg2=5&arg3=6

Choose 'raw' for request body type in Postman plugin for Chrome browser, to test this out.

also set the Header:
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded